# Total set in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Definition: A subset of a Hilbert space is total if its span is the entire space.

Halmos in his book (A Hilbert space problem book) asks  below  question:

There exists a total set in a Hilbert space that continues to be total when any one element is omitted but ceases to be total when any two elements are omitted.

Then he just gives a proof for this problem when Hilbert space is separable.

My question: How does it prove in non-separable  case?

### Please just give me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write the non-separable Hilbert space as an orthogonal sum.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks.

Comment: Little remark: Total subset usually means that the closure of its span is the entire space rather than merely its span.